# Oracle Error Has Occurred:ORA-20011: Execute_system: Error while receiving

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

After executing one package, i got the below error
Oracle Error Has Occurred:ORA-20011: Execute_system: Error while receiving.

```
     Status = 1
```

Please let me know what the error means ,why the error occurs and how to rectify the same

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has reserved the error numbers between ORA-20000 and ORA-20999 for us users. Which means that someone at your site has programmed their own user defined error. The package issues a RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20011,'Execute_system: Error while receiving.'); statement. Either directly in the package body or indirectly via a database trigger on one of the tables the package is modifying.

Regards,
Rob.